# Insert query not inserting no error message

Tags: php, mysql

I can't get an INSERT query to INSERT in db.  I am not getting any error message and was following a tutorial any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO rooms (room_title,room_description,monthly_rate,prop_name,prop_description) VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

$stmt = mysqli_prepare($dbc,$query);
//$stmt = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
if($stmt == false) {
  die("<pre>".mysqli_error($dbc).PHP_EOL.$query."</pre>");
}

mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,"ssiss",$pn,$d,$p,$ppn,$ppd);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
//mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
// Check the results...
if (mysqli_stmt_affected_rows($stmt) == 1)

  {

    echo'<p>The room has been added.</p>';                  
    // Clear $_POST:
    $_POST = array();

  }

mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);

} // End of $errors IF.
// End of the submission IF.
```

Because it does not echo "The room has been added"  I suspect the problem is with the `mysqli_stmt_affected_rows($stmt) == 1`

Comment: check the return of mysqli_stmt_execute

Comment: If `mysqli_stmt_execute` returns false, call `mysqli_error()` to get the error message.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($dbc, "INSERT INTO rooms (room_title,room_description,monthly_rate,prop_name,prop_description) VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)")) {

 mysqli_stmt_bind_param("ssiss",$pn,$d,$p,$ppn,$ppd);

mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

} printf("Error: %s.\n", mysqli_stmt_error($stmt));
```